# JSP java code says "javax.naming" doesn't exist when used in <%!

Tags: java, jsp, compiler-errors

When I write code in `<%`, I can use `javax.naming`, but when I write code in `<%!`, I get an error that `javax.naming` does not exist.

some examples:

```
<% Javax.naming.InitialContext ic = new Javax.naming.InitialContext(); %> fine
<%! void foo() { Javax.naming.InitialContext ic2 = new Javax.naming.InitialContext(); } %> error
```

The exact error:

```
rptCountsRecon_jsp.java:22: package Javax.naming does not exist
    Javax.naming.Context init = new Javax.naming.InitialContext();
```

I am sortof new to Java and am very new to JSP.

EDIT: added the foo method to the second example, because it may help understand my issue. Also added the exact error from Tomcat.
EDIT 2: tried adding the prefix to Context, and got a similar error.

EDIT 3: Side question... The current code gives the following error:

```
    try
    {
        javax.naming.Context init = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
        Context ctx = (Context) init.lookup("java:comp/env");
        String jndiName = getServletContext().getInitParameter("jndiName");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(jndiName);
        Connection dbConn = ds.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement pstmnt = dbConn.prepareStatement(sql);
        for(int i=0; i!=binds.size(); ++i)
            pstmnt.setString(i+1, binds.elementAt(i)); //binds index starts at 1 -_-

        return pstmnt.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //out.println("A naming exception occured... I don't know how to get the info of it.");
        return null;
    }

rptCountsRecon_jsp.java:28: unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        Connection dbConn = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: Post the exception message you got.

Comment: I have, and the exact problem I had, has been solved through a series of fixes, now I'm getting a new exception, probably because I don't understand Java exception handling very well =P.

Comment: New problems should go in new questions. Your initial problem is solved (even though you worsened it yourself during the edit by using `Javax` instead of `javax` as package root).

Comment: That was actually an initial problem.

I'm sorry, I just really hate Java and don't want to troubleshoot it. I'm being bitter.
I'll mark as solved and make another question. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: I don't understand why I was getting the error, but suddenly it works, yay shitty tomcat. Wtf is wrong with businesses choosing this shitty technology... Can't wait till I'm outta here and working under better technologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all this type code should be in a servlet, not in a JSP.

**Declaration** (`<%!`):

```
<%! 
    javax.naming.InitialContext ic2 = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
%>
```

`ic2` is a member variable. And the reason that you can't do `ic2 = new javax.naming.InitialContext();` there is because the constructor throws `javax.naming.NamingException`.

Imagine something as follows:

```
public class JspServlet {
    //there is no way to handle that exception here
    javax.naming.InitialContext ic2 = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
    //...
```

**Scriptlet** (`<%`):

```
<% 
    javax.naming.InitialContext ic = new javax.naming.InitialContext(); 
%>
```

And the reason that it can be done there (within scriplet) is because everything in the scriplet goes inside a `try` block of the generated JSP service method.

Imagine something as follows:

```
public class JspServlet {

    public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
             throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {             
        try {
            javax.naming.InitialContext ic = new javax.naming.InitialContext(); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            //...
        }
```

I think it will make more sense if you read more about JSP lifecycle.

Comment: @BalusC: Now it makes a lot more sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah, that shesd some light, but I think I'll need to be more specific with my problem. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: You solved one of my problems ;). I plan on marking both og them correct if I can. I'm currently waiting for additional help from rickz, or whoever is willing to give it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what Bhesh posted. But, you could do the following.

```
<%! 
   public void jspInit(){
  try{
      javax.naming.InitialContext ic2 = new javax.naming.InitialContext(); 
   } catch (javax.naming.NamingException ne){
                                             // do something when exception occurs
                                            }
   }
%>
```

The JSP container calls the jspInit method when it loads the page.

Comment: I'm not getting an exception. I'm getting a "name does not exist" error.

Comment: You are misspelling it. Java is case sensitive.

Comment: Haha, you are correct, and then I get a naming exception and your original solution likely solves that =P.

Comment: Problem solved, but now I have a new error, which confuses me. 
First of all, thanks a lot for the help.
I have other functions I'm running, so I decided to use Exception e for the catch statement to try and catch everything, but one line is still reporting "unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown".
I'll post the code block and error as an edit in my main question.